# Does the frequency of an exciting force affect the damping in a structure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vibrations

My question stems from my investigations into vibrations induced by pedestrians walking/running on bridge structures. The walking frequency for most people is between 1.4-2.4 Hz and I'm wondering if walking at a higher pace might induce larger damping from the structure.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: why do you think this might be the case? what is the motivation for your question?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of damping in a structure is set by the amount of internal friction present in it and to first order this number is not a function of the frequency with which it is perturbed. However, since a cable-suspension footbridge for example contains elasticity and mass, it will possess a natural frequency of oscillation. if the bridge is less than critically-damped and the excitation frequency is close to the resonance frequency, then the bridge's oscillations will grow in amplitude. This amplitude growth will not occur if the excitation frequency is significantly greater than the resonance frequency, which is the situation you are asking about. the system is then "mass-controlled" and the bridge might appear to be well-damped because its oscillations do not grow,  but this is because it is being driven "off resonance" and not because there is some new source of mechanical damping which becomes active under those conditions.

Comment: Thanks for answering Niels. So just to confirm, the excitation frequency has little to no effect on the absolute damping of the structure if said frequency is not close to the resonant frequency of the structure ?  Also, on the flip-side, if the excitation and fundamental frequencies are close to each other, would there then be a correlation between damping and the value of the frequency ?

Comment: question 1 = yes, and question 2 = not exactly;  if driven near the bridge's resonance frequency, then the resonance condition will be excited-  and it then becomes possible for the resonant response to overwhelm what damping there is naturally in the system.   there will be a correlation between the amplitude of the resulting vibrations and the amount of damping. little damping = big amplitude; lots of damping = little amplitude.